# Sending file via POST using fs.createReadStream doesn't send the file

Tags: node.js, electron, node-request

I have the following code. Issue is, the file isn't always getting caught by my server (hosted on DigitalOcean, not that that matters so much as I often couldn't even get it to work on my local vagrant machine).

It seems to work with smaller files, smaller images, however if I send a larger file (such as a full screen screenshot) my server is telling me that the request has been made but no 'image' has been found.

I had a look around for a way for createReadStream to return some kind of promise, in hopes that it would be as simple as it is still trying to read the image from the hard drive, but I've had no luck.

Worth mentioning that the image is being generated just before this happens, but this is being called in a callback so that shouldn't matter.

```
...
    const capture = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

    request.post({
        url: UPLOAD_URL,
        method: 'POST',
        formData: {
            'image': capture,
            'token': this.token
        },
        headers: {
            'User-Agrent': 'request',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }, (err, response, body) => {
...
```

Comment: Since it appears that you use the `request` module, I would look into the streaming feature that they provide with the package using `pipe()`. Have a look here: https://github.com/request/request#streaming

Comment: All this time later and I've just had the sudden realisation that the max file upload size in my php.ini was 2mb... Ehhh